# Java: file not found when creating an xml file

Tags: java, xml, file

I am trying to create an XML file in Java and I pass the name of the file to the function argument, but I get the error: " The system cannot find the file specified". Does anyone have any idea about this error solution? My code is like:

```
static Document loadDocument(String fileName) {
    File inputFile = new File(fileName);
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
    try {
        docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = docBuilder != null ? docBuilder.parse(inputFile) : null;
    } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return doc;
}
```

Comment: Clearly the system can't find the file. Which line is causing the problem? Is it a path or permission problem.

Comment: doc = docBuilder != null ? docBuilder.parse(inputFile) : null;    <- this line is giving the error

Comment: This code doesn't create an XML file. It parses an XML file. And the file does not exist, or is not accessible. Check the fileName. Check that it exists in the directory from which you start your program. Also, unrelated, but your code would be much more readable and logical, and wouldn't have to check for null, if everything was in a single try block.